# Create dictionary with count of each unique item from an excel column

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I have a column in excel with a header. The column contains 25-30 unique values in them and is totally 28000 rows long. I want my output to be a dictionary with keys being each unique item from the column and values being its count

```
df1 = pandas.read_excel(file,sheet)
Counter(df1)
```

above returns:

```
({"ColumnHeader":1})
```

then I tried converting the whole thing into a list

```
df2 = df1.values.tolist()

Counter(df2)
```

above returns this error message: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

This seems like a fairly commonly asked question, but I still am unable to break it down.. pls help out a newb here...

Comment: Hey, could you give us a sample of data you need this done on?

Comment: ah - sure, let me figure out hot to show df1.head() here

Comment: Highlight and use ctrl-k to format something as code. Usually makes the output of dataframes look nice.

Comment: sorry.. unable to do this right...

'code'
TYPE
0  FPTPF
1  FPTPF
2  FF
3              FAF
4              FAF
'code'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Counter` counts the items in an iterable. When you iterate over a dataframe, it iterates over the column names. That is why `Counter` is simply returning the name of the column with a count of 1. You need to count the items in a column of the dataframe, so you need to do something like this:

```
Counter(df2['ColumnHeader'])
```

Also note that when you do `df1.values.tolist()` it returns your dataframe in the form of a list of lists. However, `Counter` can only work with hashable types. Lists are not hashable.

Comment: This does it! 
this output is of type collections.Counter.. can It be a dict instead?

Comment: `Counter` is a subclass of type `dict`. But if you want it to be a pure `dict`, just use the `dict()` function on the result.

Comment: legendary! thanks vm - i now will put this on a pie chart :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to return the dictionary without using collections is

```
dict(df1["column_header"].value_counts())
```

Comment: This gives the error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: @spiff this works, but you need to use `df["column_header"].value_counts` not `df["column_header"].value`